# Instantiate a gameObject and give it a name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, game-development

I would like to Instantiate a gameObject and give it a specific name in the hierarchy, because it gives by default "gameObject(clone)", but I would like to know if there is a way to make it name the spawned object just "gameObject" and not "gameObject(clone)".
Thank you

Comment: You can rename objects using the `name` field.  eg. `myCopiedGameObject.name = "gameobject"`.

Comment: Use the "Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, randomRotation)" method;Parameter 1: is the preset Parameter, 2: The coordinates of the instantiated preset Parameter, 3: The rotation angle of the instantiated preset.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an extension method that clones an object and then sets the name of the clone to match the name of the original object.

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class ObjectExtensions
{
    public static TObject Instantiate<TObject>(this TObject original) where TObject : Object
    {
        TObject result = Object.Instantiate(original);
        result.name = original.name;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

`GameObject clone = gameObject.Instantiate();`

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the instantiate Prefab to a game object and then change the name of the game object.

Here is a sample code

```
my_spawned=Instantiate(prefab,transform.position,Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
my_spawned.name="Myobject";
```

Source: https://vionixstudio.com/2019/11/27/unity-instantiate/